# Get the highest values of the dictionary with keys until reaching given limit

Tags: python, list, dictionary

given dictionary and limit for the number of keys for the new dictionary. In the new dictionary we should have the highest number of values from given dictionary.

the given is:

```
dict = {'apple':5, 'pears':4, 'orange':3, 'kiwi':3, 'banana':1
```

I want to get a new dictionary with the highest value with key.

new is

```
{'apple':5}
```

because there should be only one

if the limit is 2.

```
{'apple':5, 'pears':4}
```

because there are three values but the limit is 2 it we don't take anything. I tried

if the limit is 3. It's still

```
{'apple':5, 'pears':4}
```

because I can't add orange. If I add it will be more than the limit.

```
new = {}
while len(new) < limit:
```

then I have to append the highest value with key in new until I reach 
    the limit. I should not add the key if it will more than the limit.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your problem is that you have

```
while len(new) < limit:
```

it needs to be `while len(new) <= limit:`

Answer (score 2):

Whole code being a function:

```
def f(d,limit):
   return dict(sorted(d.items(),key=lambda x: -x[1])[:limit])
```

And now:

```
print(f(d,1))
```

Is:

```
{'apple': 5}
```

And:

```
print(f(d,2))
```

Is:

```
{'apple': 5, 'pears': 4}
```

Note that if the dictionary is always sorted by values like the dictionary you have now, do:

```
def f(d,limit):
    return dict(d.items()[:limit])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [`most_common()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) from [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

def largest(dct, n):
    return dict(Counter(dct).most_common(n))

print(largest(dct={'apple':5, 'pears':4, 'orange':3, 'kiwi':3, 'banana':1}, n=2))
# {'apple': 5, 'pears': 4}

print(largest(dct={'apple':5, 'pears':4, 'orange':3, 'kiwi':3, 'banana':1}, n=3))
# {'apple': 5, 'pears': 4, 'orange': 3}
```

Or even with [`heapq.nlargest()`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest):

```
from heapq import nlargest
from operator import itemgetter

def largest(dct, n):
    return dict(nlargest(n, dct.items(), key=itemgetter(1)))

print(largest(dct={'apple':5, 'pears':4, 'orange':3, 'kiwi':3, 'banana':1}, n=2))
# {'apple': 5, 'pears': 4}

print(largest(dct={'apple':5, 'pears':4, 'orange':3, 'kiwi':3, 'banana':1}, n=3))
# {'apple': 5, 'pears': 4, 'orange': 3}
```

Comment: It shouldn't be {'apple': 5, 'pears': 4, 'orange': 3} when n=3 because you should also include kiwi if you include orange but if you include kiwi then it will exceed the limit so we shouldn't include both of them.